# The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core` React webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm trying to use my React native Android app working as a website.I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@naqvitalha/react-native-web-setup-with-live-reload-on-both-at-the-same-time-657a99ac521a)

when i run `webpack-dev-server` it showing below error.

[image]

**webpak.cofig.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "react-native": "react-native-web"
        }
    }
};
```

**entry.js**

```
document.write(require('./../testreact/index.android.js'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "testreact",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "firebase": "^4.1.2",
        "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.45.1",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
        "react-native-web": "0.0.104",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
        "webpack": "^3.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Remove `babel` -- `npm uninstall babel --save`

Comment: @AndrewLi you mean to uninstall babel from node_module?

Comment: Yes. `babel` was migrated to `babel-core` so `babel` is deprecated. Get rid of it.

Comment: ok i have uninstall bubble and run webpack-dev-server again .now error showing `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel' in '/home/bla/Documents/Test/React/testreact'`

Comment: Use `babel-core` instead...

Comment: i have install babel-core.but it's showing same error on my above comment.then i'v edited my  webpack config `babel` in to `babel-core` then its showing another msg.i have updated my post with that.

Answer (score 0):

In case this hasn't been solved, in your webpack `config` file use `babel-loader` instead of `babel-core`.